# Re-positioning axis labels in face_wrapped plots with free y axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a face_wrapped plot with free y axis in ggplot2. I was wondering if it is possible to reposition some of the flipped x-axis label based on the red arrows shown in the picture below?

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/surv.csv')

names(data)[2:5] <- c("Representation", "Solidification", "Application", "Confidence")

data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>% 
  mutate(name = name, 
         value = str_wrap(value, 20)) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(value, fill = name), show.legend = FALSE) + 
  facet_wrap(.~name, scales = 'free_y') + 
  coord_flip() +
  labs(y = "Students", x = "") +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=8))
```

[image]

Comment: You may need `factor` with `levels` in that order.  I guess this is similar to your previous question where the accepted answer shows `value = factor(value, levels = level_order)`

Comment: Isn't this a custom order

Comment: If that is the case, create the `count` and then use `reorder` based on `n`

Comment: Do you want the output as I posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `reorder` after creating the frequency with `count`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>% 
  mutate(name = name, 
         value = str_wrap(value, 20)) %>%
  count(name, value) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(value, n), y = n, fill = name)) + 
  geom_bar(show.legend = FALSE, stat = 'identity') + 
  facet_wrap(.~name, scales = 'free_y') + 
  coord_flip() +
  labs(y = "Students", x = "") +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=8))
```

-output

[image]

---

Or if it is a custom order, then have to create the custom order `vector` and use that to change the 'value' to a `factor` with `levels` specified in that order

```
data1 <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>% 
  mutate(name = name, 
         value = str_wrap(value, 20)) 
lvls <- unique(data1$value)[c(3, 10, 1, 5, 9, 4, 8, 7, 6, 2)]        
         
         
data1 %>%
   mutate(value = factor(value, levels = lvls)) %>% # // change here
   ggplot() + 
   geom_bar(aes(value, fill = name), show.legend = FALSE) + 
   facet_wrap(.~name, scales = 'free_y') + 
   coord_flip() +
   labs(y = "Students", x = "") +
   theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=8))
```

Comment: But the position changes don't match what I'm showing in the pic above?

Comment: @rnorouzian This is based on the frequency count. If you need a custom order, then convert the column based on the custom levels in `factor`

Answer (score 0):

This code should get the exact picture you want, by reordering the factor after you have pivoted longer

```r
data %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>%
   mutate(name = name,
          value = factor(str_wrap(value, 20))) %>% 
   mutate(value = forcats::fct_relevel(value, "Agree", after = 1)) %>%
   mutate(value = forcats::fct_relevel(value, "The assignment\nhelped me solidify\nthe key concepts", after = Inf)) %>%
   mutate(value = forcats::fct_relevel(value, "The assignment\nreflected the class\ninstructions", after = Inf)) %>%
   mutate(value = forcats::fct_relevel(value, "The assignment\nhighly reflected the\nclass instructions", after = Inf)) %>%
   mutate(value = forcats::fct_relevel(value, "The assignment\ngave me a great\nopportunity to apply\nwhat I learned", after = Inf)) %>%
   ggplot() +
   geom_bar(aes(value, fill = name), show.legend = FALSE) +
   facet_wrap(.~name, scales = 'free_y') +
   coord_flip() +
   labs(y = "Students", x = "") +
   theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=8))
```

[image]